# Error during third saturday date fetching

Tags: php, arrays, date

I want to fetch third Saturday and I am using php function for that, that i know.
But I am getting wrong data while fetching from an error.
Here is my code:

```
$frmdate = 2015-06-05;
$todate = 2015-08-31;

for ($date = strtotime($frmdate); $date <= strtotime($todate); $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date)) 
        {
            $custom_day = date("Y-m-d", $date);

            $custom_third_sat[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('third Saturday "'.$custom_day.'"'));

        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($custom_third_sat);
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: [Check This](https://3v4l.org/HKVqH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `of` like `third saturday of`:try this

```
$custom_third_sat[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("third saturday of $custom_day"));
```

*your full code can be something like this:*

```
$frmdate = '2015-06-05';
$todate = '2015-08-31';
for ($date = strtotime($frmdate); $date <= strtotime($todate); $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date)) 
        {
            $custom_day = date("Y-m-d", $date);
if(!isset($custom_third_sat[date('Y-m-d', strtotime("third saturday of $custom_day"))])){
        $custom_third_sat[date('Y-m-d', strtotime("third saturday of $custom_day"))] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("third saturday of $custom_day"));
}

        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($custom_third_sat);
```

Answer (score 6):

Every Months contain only one "third saturday" , so no need to do more looping of days. Just try this Code Once.

```
$frmdate = "2015-06-05";
$todate = "2015-08-31";
$custom_third_sat=array();
for ($date = date("Y-m-01", strtotime($frmdate)); $date <= $todate; $date = date("Y-m-01",strtotime($date."+1 Month"))) {
    if($date>$todate){
        break;
    }
    $t_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.' third Saturday'));
    if($t_date>=$frmdate && $t_date<=$todate)
    {
        $custom_third_sat[] = $t_date;
    }

}
echo "<pre>";print_r($custom_third_sat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the quotes to dates

```
<?php
$frmdate = '2015-06-05';
$todate = '2015-08-31';

for ($date = strtotime($frmdate); $date <= strtotime($todate); $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date)) 
    {
    echo"assa";
        $custom_day = date("Y-m-d", $date);

        $custom_third_sat[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('third Saturday "'.$custom_day.'"'));

    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($custom_third_sat);
```

?>